# Sorting first column of unknown number of dimensions array in java

Tags: java, arrays

Let's assume I want to have a function, in which I will sort any array's first column using Comparator. I want to pass into that function multiple dimensions array, however, each time number of this dimensions can be different. I was thinking about using generic type function, however this approach doesn't seem to work. How to do it?

UPDATE:
I was thinking about writing code like this, but this doesn't even compile, and I am not quite sure how else could I do it. I must add, that I am only considering String arrays.

```
public <T> T sortArray(T array){

        Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<T>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(T lhs, T rhs) {
                final String str1 = lhs[0];
                final String str2 = rhs[0];
                return str1.compareTo(str2);
            }
        });

        return array;
    }
```

Comment: Arraylength in java is always known. You can get the length of an array with the `length` attribute. Therefore, you always know the dimensions  ;)

Comment: What is the first *column* in a 3 or 4 dimensional array? I think the concept of a column only makes since in 2 dimensions. If you show your current code things may get clearer.

Comment: @ThomasD. The size of the second, third, fourth..... dimensions are optional in multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @CKing yes, you are right. I assumed that he always wants to order by the "first column", as he stated. What i meant is, that you always have the length of the "first column". I didn't think about the other dimensions.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please provide us with code examples of things that you have attempted otherwise, this is a low quality question because you are basically asking us to do your work for you.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change this if you want it to work for generics, but the following code will work for Objects in general (but change the casting in the compare method to cast to whatever type you pass in).

```
    public Object[][] sortArray(Object[][] array){

        Object[] columnElements = new Object[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            columnElements[i] = array[i][0];
        }

        Arrays.sort(columnElements, new Comparator<Object>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                return ((String) o1).compareTo((String) o2);
            }
        });


        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i][0] = columnElements[i];
        }

        return array;
    }
```